# How do you remove street labels on CloudMade?

Tags: leaflet, cloudmade

I would like to create a custom style on CloudMade that hides all road names/labels, but keeps the roads visible on the map. I am using this map for leaflet.js, so if I can remove the names/labels there, that works as well.

Is there a way to do this? It doesn't look like you can edit the labels in the cloudmade editor.